# Rails kaminari pagination for child table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 classes: `Posts` and `Comments`, where posts `has_many :comments` and `comments belongs_to post`.

Each of my posts has a show page with a list of comments and I would like to paginate the comments. With the current code I have, I'm showing a list of all the comments on all the pages. So, If i have 10 comments and I want to have 2 on each page, I get 5 pages with the original 10 comments on it. Could someone shed some light?

My Code:

```
Posts controller:

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments.page(params[:page]).per(3)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @post }
  end
end


"Show" views:

<%= paginate @comments %>

<% @post.comments.each_with_index do |comments, index| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= index+1 %></td>
    <td><%= comment.date %></td>
    <td><%= comment.text %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the paginated object in the view, not get them fresh from the database:

```
<% @comments.each_with_index do |comments, index| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= index+1 %></td>
    <td><%= comment.date %></td>
    <td><%= comment.text %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This gets them fresh, unpaginated:

```
@post.comments
```

Comment: The pages show correctly now. However, my indices reset every time I move to the next page. Is there a way to keep the comments in running indices, despite which page they're on? e.g Page 1 has indices 1-5, 2 has 6-10? Thanks.